# Apple Push notification service c++ / boost does not connect

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently working on a server-side push notification service with Apple push notification.
I'm working with boost asio.
Here's my code :

```
    void IPhonePush::connection() {
    std::cout << "Push iPhone connection" << std::endl;
    std::cout << getCertif() << std::endl;
    m_context.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
                          | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
                          | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);

    m_context.set_password_callback(boost::bind(&IPhonePush::get_password, this));
    m_context.use_certificate_chain_file(getCertif().c_str());
    m_context.use_private_key_file(getKey().c_str(), boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(tools::Ip::getServiceIp("gateway.push.apple.com")), 2195);
    m_socket.lowest_layer().async_connect(ep,
                                    boost::bind(&IPhonePush::handle_connection,
                                                this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void IPhonePush::handle_connection(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {
      std::cout << "/////////// Connected to PUSH SERVER !!!" << std::endl;
      start_handshake();
    } else {
      std::cout << "/////////// Error Connecting to push: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void IPhonePush::start_handshake() {
    m_socket.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                             boost::bind(&IPhonePush::handle_handshake,
                                         this,
                                         boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
```

The tools::Ip::getServiceIp gives me the ip resolved from the dns :

```
namespace tools {
  class Ip {
  public:
    static std::string getServiceIp(std::string url) {
      boost::asio::io_service io;
      tcp::resolver resolver(io);
      tcp::resolver::query query(url, "");
      tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);

      tcp::endpoint ep;
      while (iter != tcp::resolver::iterator()) {
        ep = *iter++;
        break;
      }
      return ep.address().to_string();
    }
  };
}
```

The thing is, the async_connect is called, and then nothing... handle_connection is never called not even with an error.

**I'm currently wondering if the problem is not coming from resolving the dns into an ip to connect.
If there another way to ask for a connection with an endpoint pointing towards gateway.push.apple.com directly (without resolving IP) ?**

EDIT 1 :

```
int main() {
     boost::asio::io_service io_push;
     push::IPhonePush ifpush(io_push);
     ifpush.connection();
     io_push.run();
}
```

Comment: Where do you invoke io_service::run() or equivalent?

Comment: on the main.cc : see Question edited.

Comment: If you don't think you're resolving the IP address, but don't know for sure, why not put some trace in that code to see what value is returned?

Comment: @iandotkelly: The value is correct, I have just remove the print from the code to add visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm currently wondering if the problem is not coming from resolving
>   the dns into an ip to connect.

I don't think this is the cause. Here is a sample program showing synchronous resolve and connect working just fine.

```
mac:stackoverflow samm$ cat push.cc
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int
main( unsigned argc, const char** argv )
{
    using namespace boost::asio;

    io_service io_service;

    ip::tcp::resolver resolver( io_service );
    ip::tcp::resolver::query query(
            "gateway.push.apple.com",
            "2195"
            );
    ip::tcp::resolver::iterator i = resolver.resolve( query );

    ip::tcp::socket socket( io_service );
    socket.connect( *i );
    std::cout << "connected to: " << ip::tcp::endpoint(*i) << std::endl;
}
mac:stackoverflow samm$ g++ -I /opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_system -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib push.cc
mac:stackoverflow samm$ ./a.out
connected to: 17.172.239.6:2195
mac:stackoverflow samm$
```

In my experience, problems like this are typically caused the the `io_service` running out of work or not running at all.

Comment: The issue was indeed coming from the run() statement that was not called because of some code portion blocking before ! Thanks